# jQuery add class to body when localStorage

Tags: jquery, local-storage

We use the following JS code to check localStorage and save this.

```
require(["jquery"], function (e) {
    const t = function () {
        const t = e("#togglebtw").is(":checked");
        e(".price-container .price-including-tax").toggle(!t), e(".price-container .price-excluding-tax").toggle(t), localStorage.setItem("togglebtw", t ? "true" : "false");
    };
    e(function () {
        e("#togglebtw")
            .on("click", t)
            .prop("checked", "true" === localStorage.getItem("togglebtw")),
            t();
    });
});
```

How can we also add/remove a class to the body when the #togglebtw is checked?

Comment: Do you mean "when you set checked on load" or "when the user clicks on the checkbox"? If on load, then using your existing code: `e("body").addClass("true" === localStorage.getItem("togglebtw") ? "btwchecked" : "")` ?

Comment: Pro tip: use sensible variable names.  Looks like your code has been minimised.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks! Yes indeed, that's what we mean. What should be the right total code in that case?

Comment: @freedomn-m I mean both. The class should be added to the body when the checked is loaded because of localStorage, but also when user clicks. But else it should be removed

Comment: @freedomn-m Can you help me out with the right complete code to achieve this?

Comment: Does your existing code that runs on click store to local storage correctly?  Looks like it should.

Comment: @freedomn-m My current code works perfect. But the only addition we would like to add/remove, is the body class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *toggle* a class to the body at any time with this code, example using `btwChecked` as the class.

```
e("body").toggleClass("btwChecked", "true" === localStorage.getItem("togglebtw"))
```

or, using the checkbox:

```
e("body").toggleClass("btwChecked", e("#togglebtw").is(":checked"))
```

(where `e` would normally be `$` for jquery)

as you already have `t = e("#togglebtw").is(":checked")` this becomes `e("body").toggleClass("btwchecked", t)` after that `t =`.

This uses an overload of [`toggleClass(className, state)`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state) which allows you to pass in a bool to determine if the class should be added or removed.

To add this to your existing code:, in a similar, mini-fied manner:

```
require(["jquery"], function (e) {
    const t = function () {
        const t = e("#togglebtw").is(":checked");
        e(".price-container .price-including-tax").toggle(!t), 
        e(".price-container .price-excluding-tax").toggle(t),
        localStorage.setItem("togglebtw", t ? "true" : "false"),
        e("body").toggleClass("btwChecked", t);
    };
    e(function () {
        e("#togglebtw")
            .on("click", t)
            .prop("checked", "true" === localStorage.getItem("togglebtw")),
        t();
    });
});
```

There's no need to change the doc.ready function as this calls `t()`

Comment: Thanks! I works almost perfect, but it does not remove the class when the #togglebtw is clicked. On localStorage works perfect. How can we solve that?

Comment: Good catch - I'll update.